# How to use a custom login template and still have it linked to the wp-login.php instead of creating a new page?

Tags: login

Let's say I create a custom page template for my login using this:

```
<?php wp_login_form(); ?>
```

How can I force it be used at the /wp-login.php page instead of having to create e new page and select it as a template? Now I have to create a new page with a different slug for it to work, and then disable/redirect wp-login.php to that page. This causes all kind of problems, like not being able to use "coming soon" mode plugins and so on.